# AWS Lambda throttled, but no evidence in the metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

When running Lambda in high concurrency, I receive error CloudWatch logs below (which I haven't seen anywhere else on the web!).

> Execution failed due to configuration error: Lambda was throttled while using the Lambda Execution Role to set up for the Lambda function

When I check the "Throttled invocations" metric, it doesn't show these throttles.

Why doesn't the metric show these throttles? Has anyone seen this throttle error before? It is not the usual throttle error.

Comment: Interesting.  To my eye, this is saying the Lambda service got throttled itself, internally, by another service (IAM?  STS?  S3?  EC2?  Something else?  Maybe even another component of the Lambda service?) while it was trying to access or allocate some kind of resource on your behalf ("while using the Lambda Execution Role").  Of course, that probably wouldn't be a "configuration error," although most errors that occur "while using the Lambda Execution Role" would be related to insufficient permissions on the role.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that the error message you are seeing is actually the result of some variant of a template, inside Lambda itself, that looks something like `Execution failed due to configuration error: ${internal_error}`.  Rather than a pure, proper throttling event, this was something different.  Note for example the similar patterns [here](http://dustinbolton.com/execution-failed-due-to-configuration-error-api-gateway-does-not-have-permission-to-assume-the-provided-role/) and [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16870).

Comment: I got the same error when calling aws lambda. There is no evidence in throttling metrics and in cloud watch as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was API Gateway throttling that caused this issue even though I wasn't even near throttling limits - after removing limit on API GW(going back to default settings) I haven't faced this issue anymore